# Can I replace values in a column when the subindex changes?

Tags: dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe with index ['user', 'trial, 't'], two columns x and y, and two columns with the difference of x and y. However, when the subindex 'trial' changes, the x and y values reset back to 0, so the difference is larger than it should be. Can I set the values of x_diff and y_diff to 0 as well whenever 'trial' changes, or 't' = 0

Comment: you need to show your  code

Comment: @Daan Agree with the above comment that including a snippet of your code will help people provide an answer to your question. If you type ctlr+k you can type in your code and it'll appear as if you're typing it in Spyder etc.